# Resize an iframe to fit its content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, resize

I know this is a commonly asked question but this will make me go nuts.

I need to change an `iframe` height to fit the content it has and avoid the scrollbars. I have searched for several solutions but most of them do not work for me.

Finally I used this:

```
function resize(){
var BodyH = document.body.scrollHeight;
var HeaderH = document.getElementById('main_header').scrollHeight;
var MenuH = document.getElementById('main_menu').scrollHeight;
var FooterH = document.getElementById('main_footer').scrollHeight;
parent.document.getElementById('iframe_R').style.height = (BodyH - HeaderH -MenuH - FooterH) + "px";
}
```

It seems to "work" in Chrome, but it adds an extra space that I really do not like.  It does not work in Mozilla or IE.

I know I am making some mistake, or using bad properties, or anything else. Some help will be nice.